# Opencv deciding encode fps

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, opencv, video-recording

My camera usually records video at 30 FPS, so I basically when I am recording 5 seconds of video, I usually do,

```
for _ in xrange(30 * 5):
    # read frame
    recorded.append(frame)
```

After that I save the file using

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, 30.0, (640, 480))

for frame in self.recorded:
    out.write(frame)
```

As you see I enter `30.0` as FPS argument while saving. Usually this works, and ends in an exactly 5 seconds of video. However I guess when there is some bottleneck issue, the recording fps is somewhat reduced (I am not sure of this), and the result video is very fast, like fast forwarded (still 5 seconds).

How can I resolve this issue ? do you think I misinterpreted the error ?

The code is very similar to `c++`, so a solution can be suggested by a `c++` user. I am adding it as a tag.

Comment: @Zindarod I actually do the reading in a seperate thread, and saving in the main thread, but it is not parallel, I wait the thread to end with `join()`, so you say Queue is a solution.

Comment: @Zindarod I record consequtively for 5 seconds(for example), but I don't do cpu expensive work in the same loop I read the frames. I don't even show them live, I store them in a list, to later use with saving.

Comment: @Zindarod, I actually observed that, the recording took 120 seconds, while I gave 60 seconds as parameter. So it tried to fit 120 seconds into 60 seconds, which is why it seems fast forwarded. I record sound the same way, which appears fine.

Comment: Is your code writing the same amount of frames for the good and bad case?

Comment: @Harry Yes, see the for loop above. It read correct amount of frames, but it took twice as much time to read all of them. But I save it using 30 fps as parameter, which results in a fast forwarded appearance, which is at least what I observe.

Comment: Sorry, my question targets not the code but infos about the output file. Are both files a very equal size at least?

Comment: @Harry yes, the frame count which is in resulting list seems correct. Whether there is fast output or not. The error seems to appear randomly.